# Pandas - Excel Import - Python - Glob, How to place string variable in import

Tags: python, excel, pandas, glob

Im trying to import excel files which are in a location mapped to my local Z: drive. This location contains a number of files. I'm looking to load only those which contain yesterday's date in the title.. to do this I've so far:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta

yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(1)
yesterday = yesterday.strftime('-%m-%d-%y')

all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob('Z:*[yesterday]*'):
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)`
```

---

However, the variable 'yesterday' is not called when trying to import. I know my syntax must be wrong because instead all files are being called. How do I include 'yesterday' in the condition for import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can identify as a possible problem would be the brackets around yesterday in your for loop.  `[yesterday]`

try this instead

```
for f in glob.glob('Z:*' + yesterday + '*'):
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just using if?

```
all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob('Z:'):
    if yesterday in f:
        df = pd.read_excel(f)
        all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: that returns an empty dataframe for some reason. I think it could be because there are other characters in the title. I just need the import condition to recognise that somewhere in the title, there will be 'yesterday' and to import only those which have that string.